# Error in installing package for Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs in xamarin forms

Tags: android, push-notification, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, azure-notificationhub

I am quite new to azure hubs. But spent three days to understand the flow(to use in xamarin forms).

Currently tying to link with android only(through xamarin forms). So when I thought everything needed is ready(GCM key and azure access policies) from my side, I started coding using vs2015.

First thing I did was creating "Blank portable cross platform" project.

Then,tried to install Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs package. PFA

But I am getting following errors( related to Profile259). 
I spent whole day to understand what error is saying and I understood that package is expecting different target framework than what I am referring.

So I tried changed to other versions and through some blogs I found that maybe this Profile259 directory is missing.But it's all there.

Package is expecting .Net Framework 4.5 Full Profile. I cross checked it by following the link

I updated my azure version.Nuget package is also latest.
So what could possibly go wrong.

Please guide me in right way to get push notifications in devices.

PFA below.

[image: Screenshots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add it as a component.  Go to the Components under the Android and iOS project, select edit components off the context menu, and add the "Azure Messaging by Xaramin" component.  You'll probably have to download it by clicking "Get More Components".

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Android only for now, try removing all other targets from screenshot #2. There's a chance the error message is caused by one (or all) of the Windows targets.